# Laravel Eloquent column cast as array, cannot access array

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table with a json column cast as array.

In my class:

```
protected $casts = [
    'row_ids' => 'array',
];
```

I access this column via a relationship in another class:

```
public function table_rows()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TableChannelRow::class, 'channel_api_id', 'api_id');
}
```

When I `dd` the relationship I can see the columns in the target table OK, with one of the columns containing an array as expected:

```
dd($channel->table_rows);

#attributes: array:4 [▼
  "api_id" => 2
  "table_api_id" => 1
  "channel_api_id" => 6
  "row_ids" => "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,  ▶"
]
```

In my `Blade` template page I check whether the current record `id` is in the column array like this:

```
@foreach($channels as $channel)

    @if(in_array($row->api_id, $channel->table_rows->row_ids)) true @endif

@endif
```

But this fails with:

```
Property [row_ids] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

What have I missed? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `table_rows` relationship returns a collection. So you have to loop through the collection or grab the first instance in your collection:

```
$channel->table_rows->first()->row_ids
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I just did it by `$channel->table_rows[0]->row_ids`

Comment: @TheRealPapa No problem! Just curious, does your relation always return one row? If so, maybe you should change the relation to `hasOne` instead of `hasMany`.

Comment: Perfect x2! Xie xie! I will change the relation too. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Chin Leung, I have another different Q related to this issue if you have a second ;-) ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55729084/laravel-5-8-update-mysql-json-column-cast-as-array-changes-data-stored-format